# how to convert $request format in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I search around for a bit but found nothing that did exactly what I'm after nor anything that really aided me in achieving what I'd like

I have data in this format:

```
array:4 [▼
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ty"
    1 => "word"
  ]
  "phone" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2222222"
    1 => "3333333"
  ]
  "email" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "abc@gmail.com"
    1 => "xyz@gmail.com"
  ]
  "cnic" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "567"
    1 => "234"
  ]
]
```

I'd like to convert it all to this format:

```
   [
  {
    "name" => "ty"
    "phone" => "2222222"
    "email" => "abc@gmail.com"
    "cnic" => "567"
  },
  {
    "name" => "word"
    "phone" => "3333333"
    "email" => "xyz@gmail.com"
    "cnic" => "234"
  }
]
```

i tried:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $x = count($array[0]["name"]);
    for ($i=0; $i < $x; $i++) { 
        $newArray[] = [$value["name"][$i], $value["phone"][$i], $value["email"][$i] ,$value["cnic"][$i]];
    }
}
```

but get no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it the other way around. You need to loop on the rows first (0 and 1), then in each column (name, phone, email, cnic), loop each value:

```
$newArray = [];
$count = count($array['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
        $temp[$key] = $array[$key][$i] ;
    }
    $newArray[] = $temp;
}
```

Or using `array_combine` + `array_keys` + `array_column` would work as well:

```
$newArray = [];
for ($i = 0, $count = count($array['name']); $i < $count; $i++) {
    $newArray[] = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, $i));
}
```

[Sample Output](https://www.tehplayground.com/ip5MzbE706DmndLE)

Sidenote: If this came from a form, I think this is the classic case of `<input name="name[]"` in your html form.

If you follow this kind of structure:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="input[0][name]" />
        <input name="input[0][email]" />
        <input name="input[0][phone]" />
        <input name="input[0][cnic]" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="input[1][name]" />
        <input name="input[1][email]" />
        <input name="input[1][phone]" />
        <input name="input[1][cnic]" />
    </div>
</form>
```

You would not need to do such array transposition in PHP. Once you submit the form, you already got yourself your expected array structure above. But that's just an assumption on my part.

*If it doesn't come from a form, feel free to disregard this sidenote.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
  "name" => [
    0 => "ty",
    1 => "word"
  ],
  "phone" => [
    0 => "2222222",
    1 => "3333333"
  ],
  "email" => [
    0 => "abc@gmail.com",
    1 => "xyz@gmail.com"
  ],
  "cnic" => [
    0 => "567",
    1 => "234"
  ],
];
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array["name"] as $key => $value) {
    $name = $array["name"][$key];
    $phone = $array["phone"][$key];
    $email = $array["email"][$key];
    $cnic = $array["cnic"][$key];
    $myarray = array("name"=>$name, "phone"=>$phone, "email"=>$email, "cnic"=>$cnic);
    array_push($newArray, $myarray);
}
var_dump(json_encode($newArray))
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"ty","phone":"2222222","email":"abc@gmail.com","cnic":"567"},{"name":"word","phone":"3333333","email":"xyz@gmail.com","cnic":"234"}]
```